# split string to two parts using sed or awk or perl or bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have string like this:

```
Grades ABCDEF-123456
```

I want to split this string to two sections like this

```
Grades ABCDEF
Grades 123456
```

How can I do that in bash?

Answer (score 6):

```
echo Grades "ABCDE-12345" | sed 's/-/ /g' | awk '{ print $1" "$2"\n"$1" "$3'}
Grades ABCDE
Grades 12345
```

or per @steeldriver

```
awk -F'[ -]' '{print $1, $2; print $1, $3}'
```

Comment: There's really no need for `sed` here - just set the `FS` to include `-` i.e. `awk -F'[ -]' '{print $1, $2; print $1, $3}'`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this entirely in your shell, too:

```
text="Grades ABCDEF-123456"
```

Split off the leading text. You could capture it if required, but here we'll just discard it:

```
grades="${text#* }"
```

Now we could extract the two parts as variables but for now we'll just print them:

```
echo "Grades ${grades%-*}"
echo "Grades ${grades#*-}"
```

You can also crash these together into a single output statement, but I don't think it's as readable (even if `printf` is safer than `echo` for certain classes of text):

```
printf "Grades %s\nGrades %s\n" "${grades%-*}" "${grades#*-}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by replacing the dash with a newline followed by the first field:

```
perl -alpe 's/-/\n$F[0] /'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split("-", 2); put "@a.[0]\n", @a.[0].words[0], " @a.[1]";'   file
Grades ABCDEF
Grades 123456

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '.split("-", 2) andthen put "$_.[0]\n", $_.[0].words[0], " $_.[1]";'   file
Grades ABCDEF
Grades 123456
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. There are fewer command-line flags in Raku as compared to Perl. Above, the Raku one-liner is called with `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags.

First Answer: The linewise input is `.split` on `-` hyphen into `2` pieces, and assigned to `@a` array. Note that `.split` is short for `$_.split` meaning to call the routine on the `$_` topic variable, in this case the line text. Once in the `@a` array, all we have to do is massage the data into the proper output format. Raku's `words` routine breaks text at whitespace. So the final `put` call can be understood as follows:

1. `"@a.[0]\n"` print the first element of `@a` followed by newline,
2. `@a.[0].words[0]` print the first word of the first element on the next line,
3. `" @a.[1]"` on the same (second) line, print   space then the second element of `@a`.

Second Answer: If you're comfortable using `$_` [topic variables](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topic_variable), you can forgo the array assignment and get the same output. Note in the second answer above that the `$_` is optional and the code can be further shortened: all you need is the leading `.` dot for Raku to understand that you want the routine/index called on the `$_` topic variable.

Finally, adding a key "prefix" to various text snippets is a common task. If you're comfortable with key/value pairs and can accept the default sorting, the code below might be conceptually simpler (returns `\t`-separated columns):

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my %hash = .words[0] => .words[1].split("-", 2);  \
             for %hash.sort {.antipairs.put for .invert };'   file
Grades  ABCDEF
Grades  123456
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/split
https://docs.raku.org/routine/invert
https://raku.org